# Multi-column Simple-Search from SQLite to Heroku/PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name OR username OR bio LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

The above code works fine on my development server using SQLite, but since Heroku uses PostgreSQL it breaks (seems you can only use "OR" in truly boolean queries).

Is there a better way to implement this simple search so it works with PostgreSQL or do I have to move to a more complex search solution?

Comment: Are you trying to find an object that has (name LIKE search) or (username LIKE search) or (bio LIKE search)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name IS NOT NULL OR username IS NOT NULL OR bio LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

If `name` and `username` can be NULL or empty then you'll want to use COALESCE:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where("COALESCE(name, '') <> '' OR COALESCE(username, '') <> '' OR bio LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

These should work the same in SQLite and PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't know which programming language that is and how the SQL literal gets translated, but using double quotes for character literals is not a valid syntax in PostgreSQL (and most other DBMS)

Comment: Right, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I had my single and double quotes backwards. I get my languages confused sometimes; I guess that'll teach me not to check my work. I reversed the quotes so Ruby, PostgreSQL, and SQLite should all be happy now.